Users with reputation above 500 are able to vote to close on Beta sites
For those of you that are active members of Stack Overflow and the other "established" (non-Beta) sites on the network, you probably know that it takes 3000 reputation to cast a close vote on a question.
Since Beta sites are just opening, it's too much to expect that users will reach these higher levels of reputation by the onset of the Public Beta (as during the Private Beta most of the privileges are extended to all users), so there's a shift downwards in reputation required for creating tags (to 150), retagging (to 200), editing (to 1000), voting to close (to 500), etc. (See: privileges).
So, if you see a question that's
 - a duplicate
 - off-topic
 - not constructive
 - not a real question
 - too localized
and you have greater than 15 reputation, but less than 500, you can flag the question for a moderator, but if you are over 500 and you want to exercise your close vote, please feel free to do so (see the close dialog box with the descriptions of these by clicking the Close link under the tags of any question).  If your reputation is above 500, any flagging for the abovementioned reasons is automatically converted into a close vote by the system.
Everyone is free to use or not use these privileges as you see fit, but for those who are new to Beta sites or to Stack Exchange in general, it's a bit of procedural information that might take a bit of digging around the site to find out.

Also, we have a pretty active chat so if you Vote to Close (or flag to close) then come let us know in chat. Sometimes this is necessary to get enough users to notice the post.

See also help moderate cognitive sciences yourself

@BenBrocka I had forgotten about your question/answer on that.  We can point this as a dupe of that one if you want.  I suppose it can't hurt to have the message out there twice, though.
